# Connecting to WCF, problems with single client

Tags: wcf

So I am getting the following error when connecting to the production WCF service from my development machine.  This is not a server side problem because no other user has this issue and when I use my credentials to log into another machine, it works.  Normally I would just use another machine but due to a deadline, there is not time to rebuild my dev box.   I will if that's what it takes but if someone has seen this and can advise how to fix it that would be preferable.  I do not recall changing any setting that could have caused this, however in my attempts to correct this I have changed the value in:

Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Security Options > 
Network Security: LAN manager Authentication level

I have tried all all the values that have both LM & NTLM in them.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)
at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)
at System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)
at System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at PCLIndexStats.ThirdPartyService.IThirdPartyService.get_delayed_quote_from_third_party(get_delayed_quote_from_third_partyRequest request)
at PCLIndexStats.ThirdPartyService.ThirdPartyServiceClient.get_delayed_quote_from_third_party(String symbol)
at PCLIndexStats.frmMain.btnGetData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
PCLIndexStats
Assembly Version: 1.3.4.0
Win32 Version: 1.3.4.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/fbalas/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/QR3QEJQP.VZN/OQKYBMYB.5W3/pcli..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_8df6cb5089eda551/PCLIndexStats.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
IndexDAL.1.0.0.0
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/fbalas/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/QR3QEJQP.VZN/OQKYBMYB.5W3/pcli..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_8df6cb5089eda551/IndexDAL.1.0.0.0.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data.Linq
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel.Internals
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Internals/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
----------------------------------------
SMDiagnostics
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/SMDiagnostics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/SMDiagnostics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel.Web
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
System.IdentityModel
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.IdentityModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 11.0.50727.1
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Net.Http/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Net.Http.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```